# Javascript: uploaded file enconding and generated file enconding

Tags: javascript, encoding, upload

Right now I'm creating a simple script to synchronize subtitles in .srt format which is accessible [here](https://hacdias.github.io/subtitles-sync/). The problem is that I'm creating a file to download in UTF-8 but I can't guarantee that the file that I upload initially is also UTF-8 which can lead to weird characters on the final file.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/hacdias/subtitles-sync/blob/gh-pages/javascript/app.js#L50). I would like to know how to deal with this encoding problem. Isn't there a way to know that's the enconding of the uploaded file so the final one has the same enc?

Regards,

Comment: no. you cannot reliably detect encoding, because encoding is contextual. e.g. you have a file with the characters `gift` in it. is that english ("present"), or is it german ("poison"). at best you can do an analysis of the bytes in the file and GUESS at what the encoding would be, but many encodings overlap, and the text would be equally "valid" in both.

Comment: I see. So, isn't there a way to get ride of this weird characters? I can't just simply put it do always download in ```Windows 1251```... that would create a problem for other users... what do you recommend?